# MKMapView and annotations hiding with zoom

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am using MKMapView... I am adding tousands of annotations to map, which causes slow map movements.
I want to show / hide annotations with zoom level. In each zoom I want to hide overlapping annotations. 
Is there any solution ?

So far I came up with comapring annotation bounding rectangles on overlap and remove annotation, if there is an overlap. This solution is slow, because i need to compare everything with everything (I know, I can use trees etc... ) and secondly, removing and adding annotations back to map is little slow.

What would be good, is to have access to annotation rendering and if annotation is rendered, check whether it can be or not...
Can it be done ?

Thanks

Comment: you can profit from the reusing mechanism (dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier) with so many annotations. Do you use custom annotation views (MKAnnotationView subclass)?

Comment: Yes, I use custom annotations.

Comment: I also have the map slow problem when zoom out with many annotations. I did the reusable annotations, but it doesn't improve the map movements on iPhone 4. On iPhone 5s I have no problem, considering that rendering capacity is really high.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

    NSArray *annotations = [mapView annotations];
    //NSLog(@"%@",annotations);
    CustomAnnotation *annotation = nil;
    for (int i=0; i<[annotations count]; i++) {
        annotation = (CustomAnnotation*)[annotations objectAtIndex:i];
        if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {

            if (mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta <= 0.13f) {
                [[mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation] setHidden:NO];
            } else {
                [[mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation] setHidden:YES];
            }

        }
    }

}
```

You can adjust the delta in the if condition for more comfortable

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the native SDK since iOS 11, check [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/decluttering_a_map_with_mapkit_annotation_clustering) (so-called "MapKit Annotation Clustering")